# Magento: Page won't stop loading in admin/system_config/edit/section/design

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I was using Magento 1.4.1 and upgrade gracefully to 1.4.2. After testing if the upgrade was Ok, I made some modification in order to have a new home page layout for a store using these [instruction](http://magentoexpert.blogspot.com/2010/01/magento-add-new-cms-page-layout.html). The modifications have been tested on a local version (Ubuntu 10.04, php 5.3.2), and worked great.

When I upload the files to the pre-prod server (Centos 5.5, php 5.2.14), and access the `System->Configuration->design` tab in the admin backend, my browser seems to keep loading indefinitly.

**What I have done**:

- I copied the `app/code/core/Mage/Page/*` directory to the `app/code/local/Mage/Page/`;
- I created the app/etc/modules/Mage_Page.xml, and defined the codePool to local;

**What I have already checked**:

- I got no errors in `/var/log/httpd/*.log`;
- I got no errors in magento's `var/log/system.log`;
- The frontend works fine;
- The backend can be accessed, except the `System->Configuration->design` tab;
- I tried to revert my modifications to a revision before the modification were made (using svn);
- I cleaned up the cache using `rm -fr var/cache/mage* var/session/*` directly on the server;
- I restarted the server multiple time;
- I even tried to get a dump of the db in production on the preprod server, with no effect. I still got the same issue.

If someone could point out anything I could have forgot.
I am ready to try anything to make it work, since it would not affect the production server for now.

Comment: There could be database updates happening (modules executing their database upgrade scripts) causing the hang.  It may sound stupid, but have you tried just waiting it out?

Comment: @Nick, Thanks for the feedback, I once let it run for about an half-hour, and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, we finally tried to reboot the apache server (we had to force it to reboot, I don't know why?). When we retried, everything was working as expected.

There probably was a corruption on the server that made crash only this tag.

Hope this could help someone.